# Using a Variable from a Separate Function in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am learning Swift and attempting to make use of code from the iOS8 Swift Dev's Cookbook, but am having difficulty using a variable produced from a custom function in the `viewDidLoad` function to put that product in a `UILabel` object.

The optional `phone` toward the top is not corresponding to the `phone` created `peoplePickerNavigationController` function. Thus, the labelPhone object displays nothing rather than displaying the phone number selected out of the `peoplePickerNavigationController` function.

How does one get a variable/constant from one function into an object in the `viewDidLoad` function so that it can be used in the UI?

For reference, my Storyboard contains a `UIButton` "Contacts" that can be tapped to execute the `peoplePickerNavigationController` function.

```
import UIKit
import AddressBookUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate {

    var phone : String?
    //I'm trying to pull up the phone variable down below, but the two are not corresponding. The optional above is what appears in the `labelPhone` object below rather than the contents of the phone way below.

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var labelPhone = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
        labelPhone.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
        labelPhone.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        labelPhone.text = phone
        self.view.addSubview(labelPhone)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    let personPicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        personPicker = ABPeoplePickerNavigationController()
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        personPicker.peoplePickerDelegate = self
    }

    func peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!) {
        /* Mandatory */
    }

    func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!, didSelectPerson person: ABRecord!, property: ABPropertyID, identifier: ABMultiValueIdentifier) {
        /* A property in a person was picked */
    }

    @IBAction func performPickPerson(sender : AnyObject) {
        self.presentViewController(personPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!, didSelectPerson person: ABRecordRef!) {
        /* Do we know which picker it is? */
        if peoplePicker != personPicker{
            return
        }

    /* Get all phone numbers this user has */
        let phones: ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty).takeRetainedValue()

        let countOfPhones = ABMultiValueGetCount(phones)

        for index in 0..<countOfPhones{
            let phone = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, index).takeRetainedValue() as String

            println(phone)


        }
    }

}
```

Thanks <3

Current code:

```
import UIKit
import AddressBookUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate {

var phone : String?
var labelPhone: UILabel?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    labelPhone = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
    labelPhone!.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
    labelPhone!.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    labelPhone!.text = phone
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

let personPicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    personPicker = ABPeoplePickerNavigationController()
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    personPicker.peoplePickerDelegate = self
}

func peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!) {
    /* Mandatory */
}

func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!, didSelectPerson person: ABRecord!, property: ABPropertyID, identifier: ABMultiValueIdentifier) {
    /* A property in a person was picked */
}

@IBAction func performPickPerson(sender : AnyObject) {
    self.presentViewController(personPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!, didSelectPerson person: ABRecordRef!) {
    /* Do we know which picker it is? */
    if peoplePicker != personPicker{
        return

    }

/* Get all phone numbers this user has */
    let phones: ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty).takeRetainedValue()

    let countOfPhones = ABMultiValueGetCount(phones)

    for index in 0..<countOfPhones{
        //let phone = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, index).takeRetainedValue() as String

        phone = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, index).takeRetainedValue() as? String
        labelPhone!.text = phone


        println(phone)



    }
}

}
```

Comment: `viewDidLoad` happens _long_ before anything else. So how could it possible be affected by what `didSelectPerson` will do in the future? It doesn't have a time machine...

Comment: Also the `phone` in `didSelectPerson` is _not_ the same `phone` up at the top, because you said `let` which declares a completely different local variable. But even if it were, it wouldn't matter, because it happens later. Try to think about the order in which methods are called. Use logging to help you understand.

Comment: I see. Is it possible to use the phone constant in the UI? I'm trying to put that phone number in the constant phone into a UILabel

Comment: Of course it's possible but not by using `viewDidLoad`; it happened earlier. You want to set the label's text to `phone`, then _set_ it. Don't wait and pray for it to happen magically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, viewDidLoad only execute once when the view is loaded. To change the text of the label you need to do something like:

```
var phone : String?
var labelPhone: UILabel?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    labelPhone = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
    labelPhone.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
    labelPhone.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    self.view.addSubview(labelPhone)
}

func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!, didSelectPerson person: ABRecordRef!) {
    // Got the phone 
    phone = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, index).takeRetainedValue() as String
    labelPhone.text = phone
}
```

Comment: This is almost right, but not quite... In swift "self." is not required when accessing the global variables so setting `self.phone = phone` doesn't make sense. Simply ditch the "let" in `phone = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, index).takeRetainedValue() as String`

Comment: Also since phone will equal nil originally, `labelPhone.text = phone` shouldn't at all be in the viewDidLoad.

Comment: I've been tweaking this (labelPhone needs to be unwrapped it seems otherwise I get errors among a couple other small tweaks) and have it to a point where I feel like it should be working, but I'm still not getting anything in the label. In fact when I change the labelPhone!.text to "test", "test" doesn't show up now the way it was before. About to post code above

Comment: @user3246092 Is setNeedsDisplay helping?

Comment: @user3246092 Did you forget to add UILabel to self.view?

Comment: Derp a derp. It was the self.view or lack thereof. Thank you so much skyline! This has helped me along in my project and also taught me how to program across functions in the future (let's hope)!